# Windows 10 boot error after disk partition

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I attempted to create an 18 GB partition (with 64 GB unused on a 231 GB SSD) with a disk management program (AOMEI Partition Assistant).
I pressed Apply which was followed by a restart, which resulted in the following error message thrown by the Windows Boot Manager:

```
Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer.
  2. Choose your language settings, and click Next
  3. Click "Repair your computer."
If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.
  File: \Boot\BCD
  Status: 0xc000000f
  Info: The Boot Configuration Data from your PC is missing or contains errors.
```

I booted from the Windows installation media USB and selected Start-up Repair in the Windows Recovery Environment.
The Start-up Repair option failed to fix the problem.

Comment: You will likely have to reinstall Windows if the automatic repair was unable to resolve the problem. If your BCD is corrupt that is very difficult to fix.  Providing an output of your current BCD will be required before any answer can be submitted.

Comment: _Which_ disk amangement program did you use?

Comment: @Aganju AOMEI Partition Assistant at [this site](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj9y8ao1IPvAhUpTd8KHX_QCncQFjAOegQICRAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.diskpart.com%2Ffree-partition-manager.html&usg=AOvVaw0m-u5tB2OgvkA2NC-wj6Pt)

Comment: Before making a change to disk partitioning, one is advised to make a disk image (and AOMEI, I believe, provides tools to do so). If you've done that, then by far the fastest fix is to restore the image.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I haven't done that. All I've done was deallocate a small amount of storage into a new partition, then click Apply. Is there a way to save my data on my drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save your data, **stop using the SSD in any way that allows writing to it**. For example, boot from a live USB, e.g. a [live Ubuntu drive](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview). Then [mount the SSD read only](https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/mount-file-systems-as-read-only-on-linux/) to avoid damage to the file system and its data. The use a tool such as [Clonezilla](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/free_imaging_software.html) to make a disk image.

You should be able to access all data from that disk image, rather than directly from the SSD. To be safe, make a copy all your personal files *from the image* (yes, this is redundant, but if your data has value, worth the trouble).

Now you can make changes to the SSD, such as trying to restore Windows, knowing at least the data is safe. You might be able to fix the SSD file system and find the data is still there... or you might find the data gone, except in your backups.